# centos7 yum libffi-devel failed

Tags: linux, yum

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

this is error message:

> Error downloading packages:  libffi-devel-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64:
>   [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I think you mean `centos7 yum libffi-devel failed` ... **failed**, not filed.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
sudo yum install -y libffi libffi-devel
```